# Reading file from a file converting int to str

Tags: python

I have a file with data given below , it includes **alph , int , real no , alphanumeric** :

```
    AAKzAlazNghRnKk,  gD6mLtXhOgIOqwb         ,-7,123456789,
irLpFWqlPcTSoyz, 94QdguKLborVKE7       ,1,123456789,
vtUQrAKPsWsNDQj,        a1h5UDsN1ATlKde      ,0,123456789,
wIaWGDDykPvdYjm,19K1qSJUPP0wzIO    ,7,123456789,
zcWsfLYFJlOmISg,         Yj5QfJ2J39LvOCe        ,1,123456789,
WggBwOjOjEEwaFr,kMfxDWDurNyF9j3      ,-3,123456789,
```

when I try to read data from this file line by line it is converting int into strings but I don't want that , the type should remain as it is after reading the file :

**code :**

```
with open(name,'r') as f:
    letters = f.readline().split(',')
    for l in letters:
        if l.index() == 0:
        print l, type(l)
```

**result :**

```
AAKzAlazNghRnKk <type 'str'>
  gD6mLtXhOgIOqwb          <type 'str'>
-7 <type 'str'>
123456789 <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Have you tried the pandas or numpy csv reading functionalities?

Comment: From program point of view "123456789" **is** a string.

Comment: @Basilevs before writing into file I am checking the type and then its is printing int

Comment: As @Soravux points out, [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) both provide functionality for reading in CSV's and easily formatting the output if you know the structure of the input data. numpy specifically can be told to try and convert the data to numbers if possible automatically.

Comment: You are writing to a text file. All data is converted to strings before actually getting to the file.

Comment: @n.imp Of course, it's whatever type it is before going to a file. But most files are *text* files; Python is converting your number to a string, then placing it in the file. All information about what the type was before it's written to the file is lost. You have to manually restore it. If your goal is to just save python datastructures into a file and then restore them, you might want to look into [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

The file is simply a bunch of characters and whitespace. There is no way for your code, in its present format, to know what you want each of them to be. Who's to say `-7` isn't a string!

You must define it. Here's some code, I've no idea if this works I'm just thinking out loud, apologies.

```
with open(name,'r') as f:
    letters = f.readline().split(',')
    for l in letters:
        if l.index() == 0:
        try:
            print int(l), type(int(l))
        except:
            print l, type(l)
```